# Examples of factoring in the existence proof of tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $M$, $N$, $P$ be three $A$-modules, and let $f: M \times N \longrightarrow P $ be a bilinear map. Then the tensor product $M\otimes_A N$ is by definition $F/D,$ where $F$ is the free $A$-module on the elements of $M\times N$ and $D$ is the submodule of $F$ genetated by all the elements of the type

$$(x+x',y)-(x,y)-(x',y),\ x,x' \in M,\ y \in N,$$

$$(x,y+y')-(x,y)-(x,y'),\ x \in M,\ y,y' \in N,$$

$$(ax,y)-a(x,y),\ x \in M,\ y \in N,\ a \in A,$$

$$(x,ay)-a(x,y),\ x \in M,\ y \in N,\ a \in A.$$

What is an example of 2 elements $a,b\in F$ such that $a/D = 0$ and $b/D \neq 0$ (when you quotient out $a \in F$ by elements of $D$ you get zero)? And what is $F$? Is it possible to construct a small example?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Notice that $P$ is not actually involved in the definition of $M\otimes_A N$ (although any bilinear map $f : M\times N\to P$ induces a unique linear map $M\otimes_A N\to P$ compatibly with the bilinear map $f$). Since $F$ is free, any element of $F$ which is not in $D$ will produce such a $b$, and any element of $F$ which is in $D$ will give you your $A$. But what are you really looking for here? What kind of description of $F$ do you want (and do you really want a description of $F,$ or do you want a description of $T$)?

Comment: Im looking for instructive examples of elements in $F$ and $F/D$ so that I can see the relation between $F$, $F/D$ and $T$. In the first step Im not concerned about finding examples of $T$. I know some examples of $T$. E.g the tensor product of two vectors is the outer product: $VW^{T}$

Comment: This might not be very helpful, but in practice one rarely works with $F$ or $F/D$ explicitly. Rather, one uses the universal property of $T$ to talk about tensor products and their properties. However, as an instructive example you might take $A = \Bbb{Z}$ and $M = \Bbb{Z}/(m)$ and $N = \Bbb{Z}/(n)$ for $n,m\in\Bbb{Z}.$ A question for you to figure out: when is $a(b + (m),c + (n))$ zero or nonzero in $M\otimes_A N$?

Comment: Also, elements of a quotient module $M/N$ are typically denoted $m + N,$ not $m/N$ (because the group operation on $M$ is "addition").

Comment: @Stahl, $M \times N$ is zero when $ab \in (m), ac \in (n)$. So what is quotiented out to get to get M⊗N?

Comment: $M\times N$ is never zero unless both $n$ and $m$ are $\pm1$! You are correct that $a(b + (m),c + (n))$ is zero in the quotient if $ab\in (m)$ and $ac\in (n),$ but this is not the only time this is zero. As an example, I claim that if $m = 2$ and $n = 3,$ then $(1 + (2), 1 + (3))$ maps to zero: that is, $\Bbb{Z}/(2)\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}}\Bbb{Z}/(3)\ni 1\otimes 1 = 0.$

Comment: Elements of $F/D$ are cosets like $(x,y)+D$, $(x,y)+(x',y')+D$ etc. These are denoted as $x\otimes y$, $x\otimes y+x'\otimes y'$, etc.

Comment: Yes, Ive seen that. Though i dont understand how $(1+(2),1+(3))=0$, but I have learned that if  $gcd(m, n)=1$ then $M \times N$ is the zero tensor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=\mathbb{Z}$, $M=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, and $N=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Then $M\times N$ is a set with $mn$ elements, so $F$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{mn}$. The actual elements of $F$ will be of the form $\sum_{i=1}^ka_i(x_i,y_i)$ for $a_i\in A$, $x_i\in M$, and $y_i\in N$, but with no relations. That is, there is never a way to simplify $(x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)$ (unless $(x_1,y_1)=(x_2,y_2)$) or $a(x,y)$ since $F$ is free on these ordered pairs. More generally, $F$ will typically be very large such as if $A=\mathbb{R}$ and $M$ and $N$ are some finite-dimensional nontrivial vector spaces. Then $F$ be a vector space of infinite dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$. Nonetheless, this does not matter so much since once you take the quotient by $D$, the relations turn the module into something more reasonable and useful. We don't usually work with $F$ itself.

For one last example, take $A=M=N=\mathbb{Z}$. We see that $(2,6)-2(2,3)\in D$ so that $2\otimes 6-2(2\otimes 3)=0$ in $F/D$ (being an element of $D$ is precisely what it means for something to be $0$ modulo $D$). On the other hand, $(1,1)$ is not an element of $D$ and therefore not $0$ modulo $D$.

Comment: @ Anonymous thanks! I dont fully understand the choice of $D$, but I see that $F/D$ has something to do with quotienting out the same representations of elements of a tensor. So that we move from element representation (in F) to class representation of tensor products (T).